# How is shmat() etc. implemented in the Linux kernel. Is there any other way to share memory?

Tags: c, linux, mmap, sysv-ipc

with `mmap()`, processes must inherit the mapping from a parent to share memory.  is there a way to share memory between processes that don't share a parent? `shmat()` seems to be the best solution, but it requires clean up if the processes didn't detach the memory on exit/die.

Domain sockets are close to sharing memory...

Comment: Processes can share the *backing* used for the memory map. Usually it is just the open file descriptor to the backing file on a tmpfs (in `/dev/shm/`), but there are other options, too. I did not write this as an answer, because sharing a mapping is fundamentally a different mechanism than sharing the backing used for different mappings, even if the two (can) behave the exact same way from a programmers perspective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `mmap`, processes must inherit the mapping from a parent if you use anonymous memory. However, if the mapping is backed by a file then there is no such requirement. `shmat`, aka System V shared memory, isn't without problems either - traditionally it used to be a limited resource, and one needs to play with sysctl and root to raise the limits.

With `mmap` both processes can open and map the same file, and *then* unlink the file. Now, when all the processes exit the file will also be automatically removed. Or it can be unlinked in the beginning - a server process can then share open file descriptors to clients via unix sockets.

Of course using mmap with file backing will mean that you will need actual disk space to back the mapping, and the mapping will be flushed to the disk.

If you want a mapping that is not backed by a disk file, you can use [POSIX shared memory objects](https://linux.die.net/man/7/shm_overview):

> System V shared memory (shmget(2), shmop(2), etc.) is an older shared memory API.  POSIX shared memory provides a simpler, and better designed interface; on the other hand POSIX shared memory
>          is somewhat less widely available (especially on older systems) than System V shared memory.

On Linux these are essentially just files in `/dev/shm` but the portable way to use these is to create and open them with [`shm_open`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/shm_open). Again, with this, even if the shared memory object was unlinked with `shm_unlink`, a process that has the shared memory object opened can send open file descriptors to it via unix domain sockets, and the receiver can use the descriptor to map the shared memory into its process space.

Thus something like:

```
fd = shm_open("/my_shared_mem", O_RDWR|O_CREAT, 0700);
ftruncate(fd, 64 * 4096);
shared_mem = mmap(NULL, 64 * 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0)
```

in the first process, second can open with `O_RDWR` and doesn't need to truncate. To remove the shared memory object, use `shm_unlink`:

```
shm_unlink("/my_shared_mem");
```

which will immediately unlink it from `/dev/shm`; those processes that have it opened can continue using it; the object is actually removed only when every process stop using it.

Comment: thank you.  so a process could create and truncate a file, say, /dev/shm/mem and mmap it.  and another process could open /dev/shm/mem and mmap it.  then would there be no need for fsync, msync.. to ensure immediate changes?

Comment: @JackAndrews no, fsync doesn't apply; and msync is used to to *flush* the changes onto disk for ordinary mmapped files; if the processes map the same file using MAP_SHARED, they will see share the exact same shared ram pages in their process space.

Comment: thank you for your clarification on shared maps and backing files.
i have no interest in portability, so would it be better, worse or same to open, map, unlink a file in /dev/shm/?  [rather than shm_open..]

Comment: you should use `shm_open` naturally. It handles many edge cases

Comment: Source for shm_open here: https://github.molgen.mpg.de/git-mirror/glibc/blob/20003c49884422da7ffbc459cdeee768a6fee07b/sysdeps/posix/shm_open.c#L31 it sets for example "close on exec" flag on the opened fd so that it isn't persisted over forks

Comment: I'm avoiding dependencies so I can select the important bits from http://code.metager.de/source/xref/lib/eglibc/libc/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/shm_open.c

Comment: @JackAndrews  Avoid dependencies to what? This is built into glibc. What exactly are you intending to do?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136948/discussion-between-antti-haapala-and-jack-andrews).